# Computation time GAM

Tags: r, windows, runtime, gam, mgcv

I am fitting the below GAM in `mgcv`

```
m3.2 <- bam(pt10 ~
            s(year, by = org.type) +
            s(year, by = region) +
            s(org.name, bs = 're') +
            s(org.name, year, bs = 're'), 
          data = dat, 
          method = "fREML", 
          family = betar(link="logit"), 
          select = T, 
          discrete = T)
```

My `dat` has ~58,000 observations, and the factor `org.name` has ~2,500 levels - meaning there are a lot of random intercepts and slopes to be fit. Hence, in an attempt to reduce computation time, I have used `bam()` and the `discrete = T` option. However, my model has now been running for ~36 hours and still has not fit nor failed and provided me with an error message. I am unsure how long might be reasonable for such a model to take to fit, and therefore how/when to decide to kill the command or not; I don't want to stop the model running if this is normal behaviour/computational time for such a model, but also don't want to waste my time if `bam()` is stuck going around in circles and will never fit.

**Question:** How long might be reasonable for such a model to take to fit / what would reasonable computation time for such a model be? Is there a way I can determine if `bam()` is still making progress or if the command should just be killed to avoid wasting time?

My computer has 16GB RAM and an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565u processor (CPU @ 1.80GHz). In my Windows Task Manager I can see that RStudio is using 20-30% CPU and 20-50% memory and that these usage values are changing and are not static.
[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what `bam()` is doing, you should have set `trace = TRUE` in the list passed to the `control` argument:

```
ctrl <- gam.control(trace = TRUE)
m3.2 <- bam(pt10 ~
            org.type + region, # include parametric terms for group means
            s(year, by = org.type) +
            s(year, by = region) +
            s(org.name, bs = 're') +
            s(org.name, year, bs = 're'), 
          data = dat, 
          method = "fREML", 
          family = betar(link="logit"), 
          select = TRUE, 
          discrete = TRUE,
          control = ctrl)
```

That way you'd get printed statements in the console while `bam()` is doing it's thing. I would check on a much smaller set of data that this actually works (run the example in `?bam()` say) within RStudio on Windows; I've never used it so you wouldn't want the trace output to only come once the function had finished, in a single torrent.)

Your problem is the random effects, not really the size of the data; you are estimating 2500 + 2500 coefficients for your two random effects and another 10 * `nlevels(org.type)` + 10 * `nlevels(region)` for the two factor by smooths. This is a lot for 58,000 observations.

As you didn't set `nthreads` it's fitting the model on a single CPU core. I wouldn't necessarily change that though as using 2+ threads might just make the memory situation worse. 16GB on Windows isn't very much RAM these days - RStudio is using ~half the available RAM with your other software and Windows using the remaining 36% that Task Manager is reporting is in use.

You should also check if the OS is having to swap memory out to disk; if that's happening then give up as retrieving data from disk for each iteration of model fitting is going to be excruciating, even with a reasonably fast SSD.

The random effects can be done more efficiently in dedicated mixed model software but then you have the problem of writing the GAM bits (the two factor by smooths) in that form - you would write the random effects in the required notation for {brms} or {lme4} respectively as `(1 + year | org.name)` in the relevant part of the formula (or the `random` argument in `gamm4())`.

{brms} and {gamm4} can do this bit, but for the former you need to know how to drive {brms} and Stan (which is doing HMC sampling of the posterior), while {lme4}, which is what {gamm4} uses to do the fitting, doesn't have a beta response family. The {bamlss} package has options for this too, but it's quite a complex package so be sure to understand how to specify the model estimation method.

So perhaps revisit your model structure; why do you want a smooth of `year` for the regions and organisation types, but a linear trend for individual organisations?

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I am expecting that the effect of both ```org.type``` and ```region``` will change through time - this is why I included a smooth of ```year``` for both ```org.type`` and ```region```. Is there another way that I could account for these two effects changing through time without including the main effect of ```year``` multiple times? I note that in another post elsewhere you suggest that when using a factor ```by``` smooth you MUST also include the factors as parametric terms in the model, so my model should also have ```org.type``` and ```region``` as parametric terms.

Comment: I have also tried including ```s(org.name, year, bs = 'fs')``` in the model instead of separate random intercepts (```s(org.name, bs = 're')```) and slopes (```s(org.name, year, bs = 're')```), but the model fails to run due to lack of memory - ```cannot alocate vector of size 4.6 Gb```. I got this suggestion from here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575538/estimating-separate-smooths-for-a-factor-with-hundreds-of-levels-using-gams), where you suggest this is computationally more efficient when random effects have many levels, in my case ~2500 levels.

Comment: For 1) you can do `s(x) + s(x, f1, bs = "sz") + s(x, f2, bs = "sz")` where `x` is your `year` and `f1` and `f2` are your two factors, respectively. I think you can also just do `s(x) + s(x, f1, f2, bs = "sz")`, but I haven't tried that yet. And yes, also, you need the parametric terms `org.type` and `region` in the model you used (and what's in my answer) but **not** in the `"sz"` basis models I mentioned here as the latter include the group means while normal factor-by smooths do not.

Comment: As for comment 2) `s(year, org.name, bs = "fs")` is going to be way easier to estimate than `s(year, by = org.name)` if there are a lot of levels in the factor because you are only estimating a single smoothing parameter with the fs version instead of `nlevels(org.name)` smoothing parameters in the factor by version. None of these are going to result in models that can be fit in a small amount of time or memory. For the size of data you are talking about (the special case of random effect terms (inc random smooths)) you are going to need a machine with lots of compute cores and lots of RAM

Comment: As an example, I am fitting models of similar complexity to your setting (actually significantly more complex models, but similar numbers of grouping factor levels) on a 40 core workstation with 256GB of RAM, and these models can take tens of hours or days to fit, although it is the memory bottleneck that you'll hit first - random effects as splines and random splines (fs) just aren't efficient memory-wise currently in mgcv as it doesn't currently use sparse matrices & linear algebra that can exploit the sparsity of the model matrices & derived matrices needed during fitting.